# Moving resources out of a generic class

Tags: c++, c++14

In a context as the one that follows :

```
template <class T>
struct MyStruct
{
    T resource; 
    decltype(auto) getResource()
    {
        return std::move(resource); 
    }     
};
```

is my `getResource` method doing what I expect it to do, i.e. move the `resource` member out of the class ? I want to use it in cases where `MyStruct` won't be used any more and it's ok to "steal" memory from it.

Comment: If you steal something you'd better stick with some more elaborate name — as far as I can tell by seeing **get** people usually don't expect modification.

Comment: decltype(auto) is C++14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
template <class T>
struct MyStruct
{
    T resource; 
    decltype(auto) getResource()
    {
        return std::move(resource); 
    }
};
```

`decltype(auto)` is `T&&`. but `T&&` by itself doesn't steal the resource, (but allows it to be stolen implicitly).

An alternative would be

```
template <class T>
struct MyStruct
{
    T resource; 
    T takeResource()
    {
        return std::move(resource); 
    }
};
```

Here, once `takeResource` is called, the resource has been transferred.

So for example

```
MyStruct<std::unique_ptr<int>> foo; foo.resource = std::make_unique<int>(42);
*foo.get_resource() = 51; // No transfer ownership, just get a reference
*foo.get_resource() = 69; // still works.
```

but

```
*foo.get_resource() = 51; // Transfer ownership, and resource will be released here
*foo.get_resource() = 69; // dereferencing nullptr -> UB.
```

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what is `T` and how its move constructor was written. If it is ,for example, an `int`, it just copies it. If it an `std::unique_ptr`, it will do what you expect exactly .

For better understanding see this example please:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class copyable{
public:
    copyable():x(0){};
    ~copyable()=default;
    copyable(copyable const&)=default;
    copyable(copyable&&)=default;

    int x;
};

class moveable{
public:
    moveable():x(new int{0}){};
    ~moveable(){
        delete[] x;
    };
    moveable(moveable const&)=delete;
    moveable(moveable&& other){
        this->x=other.x;
        other.x=nullptr;
    };

    int* x;
};

template <class T>
struct MyStruct
{
    T resource; 
    decltype(auto) getResource()
    {
        return std::move(resource); 
    }     
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct<copyable> a;
    std::cout << a.resource.x <<"\n";

    MyStruct<moveable> b; 
    std::cout << "address: "<< b.resource.x << "\tval: " << *b.resource.x <<"\n\n";

    auto temp_a=a.getResource();
    std::cout << temp_a.x <<"\n";

    auto temp_b=b.getResource();
    std::cout << "address: "<< temp_b.x << "\tval: " << *temp_b.x <<"\n\n";


    std::cout << a.resource.x <<"\n";
    std::cout << "address: "<< b.resource.x << "\tval: " << /* *b.resource.x <<  THIS IS UB */ "\n\n";

}
```

Output:

> ```
> 0
> address: 0x2d366f0    val: 0
>
> 0
> address: 0x2d366f0    val: 0
>
> 0
> address: 0    val:
> ```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/5n5je)

Answer (score 0):

`std::move` does not move on its own, it is a slight misnoma. [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) here only ensures an rvalue. Your Type T also need to have a constructor to allow for actually moving it.

All in all you can not ensure that your resource is not copied.

Pass a [unique pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) around if you want to be explicit who owns a unique resource at a certain time. unique pointer is generic and would likely be the thing you end up implementing if you refine your design long enough.

Comment: std::uniuqe_ptr will allocate the memory in the heap which may not be suitable case for the OP

Comment: @HumamHelfawi `unique_ptr` does not allocate memory on the heap. `make_unique` may.

Comment: @juanchopanza it seems that I miss something. You mean I can make a std::unique_ptr to point to stack allocated object?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi That's not the point, but sure you can. The point is `unique_ptr` is not in charge of allocation. It doesn't "allocate" anything.

Comment: @juanchopanza but when the unique_ptr moves and the stack allocated object will not. right? it may be pointing to a dead object?

Comment: It depends. I don't know what it means for the stack not to move.

Comment: I meant the stack-allocated object...  thanks for your time:) I will continue reading about it by self ;)